# python-mode documentation for Emacs

Tags: python, emacs

I just installed the python-mode in Emacs and it seems to be working well. However, I could not find documentation for the package on [the official site](https://launchpad.net/python-mode).

The package comes with a `doc` folder where I can see two files:

```
commands-python-mode.org
commands-python-mode.rst
```

Both files seem to be formatted for some external tool that displays the help text.

With this:

- Is there a tool I can use to navigate this documentation?
- Does python-mode have an online site with documentation? Any tutorials or good walk-throughs for python-mode for Emacs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cursory inspection of [those two files](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~python-mode-devs/python-mode/python-mode/files/head:/doc/) and [the code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~python-mode-devs/python-mode/python-mode/view/head:/python-mode.el) tells me that they're basically a listing of the docstrings found in `pymacs.el` and `python-mode.el`. That means you'll be able to access the relevant documentation through `M-x apropos` or `C-h a` and friends (specifically, search for `^py` or `^pymacs` to get a listing of the mode functions).

As a general rule, because `elisp` doesn't support namespaces, all functions/variables defined by a given mode will have a consistent prefix related to the name of the mode. That makes it fairly simple to search through the Emacs documentation.

Answer (score 9):

Start off with `M-x describe-mode`. This gives you an overview over the available key bindings. For each command use `C-f name RET` to see the built-in documentation. The `.org` file should be an `org-mode` file and easily readable with Emacs.

See also [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140126011914/http://www.python.org/doc/QuickRef.html#Emacs)

Answer (score 1):

If your a emacs user and haven't heard of `org-mode` before your in for treat.

Open the `.org` file in emacs and go to org-mode (<kbd>META</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>`org-mode`), use <kbd>TAB</kbd> on the header lines. Header-lines starts with one or more `*`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to answers given: Try a walkthrough of the menu "Python", which appears at the head of window. It will display a short description of the commands or options.

WRT to beginnners, some introduction, examples of basic usage might be given still.
Filed a feature request:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1281970